# yarn set version not working. Can't change from yarn 3.0.0 to yarn 2.0.0

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

current yarn version is yarn 3.0.0.
Tried changing to yarn 2.0.0 using `yarn set version 2.0.0-rc.30`.
Even after that yarn version still remains at yarn 3.0.0.

Other alternatives I tried:
`npm uninstall -g yarn` then `npm install -g yarn`. Still yarn version remains at 3.0.0.

Update:

- managed to get yarn version to 2.0 after deleting yarnrc file from root directory.

Comment: How exactly did you do this? Got the same issue

Comment: Turns out everything worked when I deleted yarnrc file from root folder.

Comment: I'd suggest commenting out the yarnPath from the yarnrc.yml rather than deleting it entirely, but helpful.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found if you have `yarn.lock` file (even an empty one) `yarn set version` stops working

Comment: I got it working by deleting `yarn.lock` as well as the `.yarn` directory, removing `yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.0.2.cjs` from the `.yarnrc.yml` file, running `yarn set version stable` again, and then adding `yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.0.2.cjs` to the `.yarnrc.yml` file again.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
$ yarn --version
3.3.1

$ yarn set version berry
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://repo.yarnpkg.com/3.3.1/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.1.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 299ms

$ yarn --version
3.3.1

$ yarn set version 2.4.2
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://repo.yarnpkg.com/2.4.2/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-2.4.2.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 346ms

$ yarn --version
2.4.2
```